# Is it correct the word "footprint" referred to the space occupied by a machinery inside a factory?

Tags: single-word-requests

The question is referred to the bulk of pasta producing machinery. I found several texts that say "footprint" but according to what I f

Comment: [**footprint**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/footprint) - *the amount of space on a surface that something needs.*

Comment: Silvia, please complete your question and provide some more context. Please include a sample sentence where you want to use the term, and some indication of the intended audience. Also, please be explicit as to what the allocated space allows for, such as aisles for forklifts and man lifts, ventilation space, utility spaces, necessary maintenance clearances, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is correct.
   [Here](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/136/equipment-footprint) Is Techopedia’s definition:

> Equipment footprint refers to the physical space a computing device or equipment requires when being placed or deployed within a home, office or computing facility. It is generally equated in terms of size in square feet / meters of area that the device will consume in a physical location and its impact on the overall space.

Comment: I agree with Jim's answer.  It may also include the required space around the device that is needed to make it function.  For example a metal forming press might need an operator sitting at the press to operate it.  The footprint would have to include the required space for that operator.